# What is the lambdaj code for the following iteration

Tags: lambda, lambdaj

The following is the code which normally write to iterate and based on some condtion,i am adding to some other list.How can i write the same in the Lambdaj.
Thanks in advance and your suggestion is appreciable.

```
List<Person> authorizedPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();
 for(Person person : Pesrsons) {
  if(person .getAuthorized()) {
    authorizedPerson.add(person);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the answer for the above,I investigated and found the solution,
If it is wrong please correct me.

```
 List<Person> authorizedPesrson = select(persons, having(on(Person.class).getAuthorized().equals(true)));
```

Comment: Correct, but you can omit the equals(true)